# Get Paragraph in Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word

I create a table of figures programmatically in a Word document.

Well, the ToF style is centered and I would like it to be left indent.
To do so (set paragraph indention) I have to get the paragraph where the ToF is located.

This is the way rto access the ToF:

```
wordApp.ActiveDocument.TablesOfFigures[1]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you want to choose a answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below. Assuming that TablesOfFigures[1] is exists (otherwise we will get buffer overflow).

```
// Check in which paragraph TablesOfFigures[1] is found
for (int i=1; i <= wordApp.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
{
    if (IsInRange(wordApp.ActiveDocument.TablesOfFigures[1].Range, wordApp.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs[i].Range))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ToF is in paragraph " + i);
    }

}

// Returns true if 'target' is contained in 'source'
private bool IsInRange(Range target, Range source)
{
    return target.Start >= source.Start && target.End <= source.End;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the code but the ToF (absolutely sure that is defined) was not found! Any Ideas?

Comment: This is strange.. If it's ok with you maybe you can upload the Word file you are working on (or at least a similar file), so I can take a look.

Comment: The file is an existing file which I open to Word application via code, and add a ToF to by attaching a template which the ToF is already defined. May these details will discover the point?

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you only have one Table of Figures, you can try this:

```
 With wordApp.ActiveDocument.TablesOfFigures(1).Range

     'Setting the indent
     .ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = CentimetersToPoints(1)

 End With
```

I have tested it just using Word and it Selects the Table of Figures and then Indents it by 1cm